# Tools for nightly unit test c project

Tags: git, unit-testing, tdd, teamcity, nightly-build

I'm looking for suitable tools using which I can perform a nightly unit test. I've an embedded c project in git, and I'm using teamcity  for  nightly build.
The challenge I'n facing is, teamcity can build the project but it can't run it, where as the unit test framework generate results during  run time only.

Help me in this regard.

Thanks,
Ajish

Comment: What Unit Test framework are you using? Normally unit tests run at build time, not runtime

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the response. I'm using Cpputest

Comment: Please find the link https://cpputest.github.io/

Comment: The Cpputest start testing from a main () function, so I assume it should be run time, please correct me if I'm wrong. Also Please suggest me a unit test framework which can run at build time.

Comment: A brief look at the docs says, "You do need to create a main where you run all the unit tests", The main method is only for running the test suite, not running your application. An alternative framework would be cppunit.